# Какую консоль использовать

Tags: веб-программирование, консоль

Вопрос покажется слишком обширный, но всё же...

Кто то рекомендует `Sublime Text`, кто то `Dreamweaver` их уима, но уверен что если привыкнуть к одному то потом сложновато перейти на что то другое.

Или в конце концов придётся тратить время на изучение и адаптацию, по этому лучше изначально решить что использовать, подскажите что для `Web` лучше использовать при изучений `Python`.

Comment: Это называется текстовый редактор/IDE. Если кто-то рекомендует, то почему вы их не слушаете, а приходите сюда за еще одной рекомендацией?

Comment: Логично - но!, как и большинство изучаю всё по видео туториалам, и не смотрю только один, вот и получается что в одном видео рекомендуется одно в другом второе, решил спросить так как считаю что многие сталкиваются с этим вопросом

Comment: Изучайте языки и технологии, а не редакторы. Базовые технологии, а не инструменты. Чтобы комфортно было в любом редакторе, потому что одно дело знать, что должна быть кнопка/пункт меню для вызова некоторой функции в любом редакторе, другое - привыкнуть тыкать в зеленую стрелку, хз, что она делает, но так надо. Упрощайте процесс работы до тех пор, пока не начнете **понимать** каждый этап. Поэтому многие советуют начинать с голой консоли и простого текстового редактора (без адовых плагинов для препроцессинга, лайв-релоадинга и черт его знает, чего еще).

Comment: И, да, "время на изучение и адаптация" к тектовому редактору - это нонсенс) Видосы - это, конечно, хорошо для совсем начала, но не ограничивайте себя ими, читайте толстые книги.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самые лучшие - *PyCharm* и *SublimeText*. Первое - полноценная среда разработки, которая обеспечивает множество сторонних пакетов, в том числе и для Web-разработки. Я думаю, что новичку будет сложновато с таким многообразием, да и скачивать нужно кряк. Поэтому SublimeText и поныне один из лучших - легкий, быстрый, удобный. С ним просто и легко работается. А серийников в Интернете куча!